# source and target functions in igraph package in R

Tags: r, graphs

What are the source and target functions in igraph package in R?  so that source(s->t) = s and target(s->t) = t

I am working on this directed graph example:

```
require(igraph, quietly=TRUE)
bsk <-read.table("http://www.dimiter.eu/Data_files/edgesdata3.txt", sep='\t', dec=',', header=T)

bsk.network <- graph.data.frame(bsk, directed=T)
```

edit: I am trying to write a function like this:

```
f_source <- function(str,network){
 result <- head_of(network, E(network)[str]); 
}

f_source(AA%->%DD,bsk.network)
```

The problem is the string. It includes quotations while E(network)[str] does not work with quotations.

Comment: The problem is what string? I don't see any strings except the file name. Create a test graph dataset we can all use and give an example and show the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g <- sample_pa(5)
```

you got

```
ends(g, E(g))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    1
# [2,]    3    1
# [3,]    4    1
# [4,]    5    2
```

and

```
head_of(g, E(g))
# + 4/5 vertices:
# [1] 2 3 4 5

tail_of(g, E(g))
# + 4/5 vertices:
# [1] 1 1 1 2
```

`source()` is an important base function.

Comment: I edited my question. please take a look.

Comment: I don't understand what you need from the edit. You can query edges like this: `E(g)[from("2") & to("1")]`. Please add a full reproducible example with a sample graph, your function and the reason, why the output of the function is not what you want.

Comment: I need two functions called f_source and f_target in my code and I want to subset on specific edges. How can I do that?